# Issues compiling the SDL 2.0.0/2.0.1 Source under Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, visual-studio-2013

I have thought about trying to compile a statically linked version of SDL 2.0.0/2.0.1 using one of the provided solutions (Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition under Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition). Unfortunately, it was unable to compile properly. After doing a bit of research, it might be a bug with Visual Studio 2013

Here are some of the errors:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ftoui3 referenced in function _SDL_HashDollar   D:\Source Code\SDL2-2.0.1\VisualC\SDL\SDL_gesture.obj   SDL2
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __dtoui3 referenced in function _SDL_PrintFloat   D:\Source Code\SDL2-2.0.1\VisualC\SDL\SDL_string.obj    SDL2
Error   9   error MSB3073: The command "copy "D:\Source Code\SDL2-2.0.1\VisualC\\SDL\Win32\Debug\SDL2.dll" "D:\Source Code\SDL2-2.0.1\VisualC\tests\testplatform\Win32\Debug\\SDL2.dll" :VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132 5   testplatform
```

For anyone else having issues with it, might need to use Visual Studio 2012 or earlier for now until there is a fix (at least the for the unresolved external symbol errors with __ftoui3 and __dtoui3) for Visual Studio 2013. Either that, use another compiler instead.

How can I build SDL from VS 2013?

Comment: ok I'll fix the question =)

Comment: [Did you see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19707916/2065121) - it sounds like somebody got it working. Might be worth investigating.

Comment: it didnt worked on my windows8 =\

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to build it: you need to change code generation of the SDL project to use /arch:SSE to prevent SSE2 floating point functions from being implicitly called. After that this problem is gone.

Comment: I found this in VC 2013 with an AMD A10, wonder if it happens in Intel processors...